# Regex for a string of length 9 and format of AAANNNNNA ?

Tags: regex

I want regular expression for a string of length 9 and with format of

AAANNNNNA

A- Alphabetic, N-Numeric

And also for AAANNNNNN

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a 'give me the codez' site. At least show you've put SOME effort into figuring this out for yourself.

Comment: Agree with Marc B. You might try http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=heb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=regular%20expression%20tutorial&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=801755ba51f49d24&ix=heb&ion=1&ix=heb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=801755ba51f49d24&biw=1096&bih=961&ix=heb&ion=1

Comment: Or, my personal favourite: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one: `[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]`

Second one: `[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{6}`

Combined: `[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z0-9]`

You can simplify this by using `\d` to represent digits: `[a-zA-Z]{3}[\d]{5}[a-zA-Z\d]`

How it works:

`[]` is a character class. `a-z` means the range `a` to `z`, `A-Z` is the same for caps, `0-9` is `0` to `9`. The use of `{}` afterwards means repeat, so `{3}` means repeat the previous pattern 3 times.

Regex isn't that hard to learn, go read up on it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/